how to limit number of rows on joined queries in typeorm?
    const consultant = await consultantRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select([
        'consultant.created_at',
        'consultant.id',
        'consultant.department',
        'consultant.average_rating',
        'review.id',
        'review.rating',
        'review.comment',
        'review.created_at',
      ])
      .from(Consultant, 'consultant')
      .where('consultant.id = :id', { id })
      .andWhere('consultant.status = :status', { status: 'active' })
      .leftJoin('consultant.review_consumed', 'review')
      .orderBy('review.created_at', 'DESC')
      .take(1)
      .getOne()

Suppose there are seven rows with oneToMany relationship with review_consumed table. I wanted to get a single row so I wrote .take(1) here but got all like below:
{
    "id": 4,
    "created_at": "2024-04-17T10:31:25.890Z",
    "average_rating": 4,
    "department": "general",
    "review_consumed": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2024-05-19T03:23:09.205Z",
            "comment": "note1",
            "rating": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2024-05-19T03:23:09.205Z",
            "comment": "note2",
            "rating": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2024-05-19T03:23:09.205Z",
            "comment": "note3",
            "rating": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "created_at": "2024-05-19T03:23:09.205Z",
            "comment": "note4",
            "rating": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "created_at": "2024-05-19T03:23:09.205Z",
            "comment": "note5",
            "rating": 5
        }
    ]
}

I want to get a single object in review_consumed array.but i got all data from this table.
i couldnt find any proper guidance or solutions in the internet yet. i didnt tried subqueries though.

you can use: leftJoinAndSelect:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77855490/typeorm-querybuilder-limit-join-to-one-record

To limit the relationship data rows in typeOrm, you need to make two queries:
 //  Fetch consultant needed
         const consultant = await consultantRepository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select([
    'consultant.created_at',
    'consultant.id',
    'consultant.department',
    'consultant.average_rating',
    'review.id',
    'review.rating',
    'review.comment',
    'review.created_at',
  ])
  .from(Consultant, 'consultant')
  .where('consultant.id = :id', { id })
  .andWhere('consultant.status = :status', { status: 'active' })
  .getOne()

   // make another query of reviews
   
   consultant.review_consumed =  await this.ReviewRepo
  .createQueryBuilder('review')
  .where('review.consultant= :id',{consultant.id});
  .limit(1) // Set the desired limit here
  .orderBy('review.created_at', 'DESC')
  .getMany()
             
      //return consultant

